# Selenium WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: docker, selenium, google-chrome, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

I do have a WebJob (running on docker ubuntu) to open an URL and get the html result (string) using Selenium and ChromeDriver. It runs fine in my dev machine (Windows 10), but when it comes to Linux Ubuntu 20 it doesn't work. I've tried several configs and args I've seen all around the web but I'm not that used to Linux. Error message is:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
(chrome not reachable)
(The process started from chrome location /driver/ is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

This is the running part of my dockerfile:

```
# run
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-focal-amd64 as runtime

RUN apt update && apt install -y sudo unzip
RUN sudo apt install -y wget

RUN wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_amd64.deb
RUN sudo apt install -y ./wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_amd64.deb
RUN sudo apt install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer

RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN sudo apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

RUN mkdir driver
RUN mkdir userprofile
RUN wget -q --continue -P driver https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/103.0.5060.53/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip ./driver/chromedriver* -d ./driver
ENV PATH=$PATH:/driver

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app/src/WebJobPDF/publish ./

ENTRYPOINT ["./WebJobPDF"]
```

And this is my C# code:

```
      ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
      options.BinaryLocation = (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux) ? "/driver/" : null);
      options.AddArgument("--headless");

      if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
      {
        options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
        options.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=/userprofile");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-setuid-sandbox");
        options.AddArgument("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
      }

      using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(options))
      {
        driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        Int64 pageHeight = (Int64)driver.ExecuteScript("return document.body.scrollHeight");

        for (int i = 0; i < pageHeight; i += 100)
        {
          driver.ExecuteScript($"window.scrollBy(0, 100)");
        }

        driver.ExecuteScript($"document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].remove();");
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        driver.ExecuteScript($"document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0].remove();");
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        driver.ExecuteScript(@"document.querySelectorAll(""button[aria-label='Gerar PDF']"")[0].remove();");
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        driver.ExecuteScript(@"document.querySelectorAll(""div[role='alert']"")[0].remove();");

        result = driver.PageSource;
      }
```

Do you have an idea about what's missing on Ubuntu for this to run?

Comment: Is chrome. Exe installed in Ubuntu machine and check if is not in individual user directory but  in common directory

Answer (score 0):

I made it working using Firefox (GeckoDriver) when running on Linux:

```
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
      {
        FirefoxOptions optionsFF = new FirefoxOptions();
        optionsFF.AddArgument("--headless");

        using (var driverff = new FirefoxDriver("/usr/bin", optionsFF))
        {
          driverff.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080);
          driverff.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
          driverff.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
          Int64 pageHeight = (Int64)driverff.ExecuteScript("return document.body.scrollHeight");

          for (int i = 0; i < pageHeight; i += 100)
          {
            driverff.ExecuteScript($"window.scrollBy(0, 100)");
          }
          driverff.ExecuteScript(@"document.querySelectorAll(""div[role='alert']"")[0].remove();");

          result = driverff.PageSource;
        }
```

When running on Windows ChromeDriver works fine.

The only problem now is wkhtmltopdf seems to be NOT working for HTTPS images. I still don't have a solution for this.